# How can I pass a non-static class method as a callback function in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, callback

An audio library I'm using takes a callback function as an argument, which writes audio into a buffer.

I'm writing a class called `Instrument`, in which I have a method `oscillator()` which writes a sine wave to the buffer:

```cpp
class Instrument {
private:
   int oscillator(int16_t* outputBuffer, ...){ // Writes a sine wave to outputBuffer
      ...
   }  
   RtAudio output;  // Object for outputting audio

public:
   void start() {
      output.openStream(settingsAndStuff, &oscillator);  // Error here
      ...
   }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like this, saying the type of the `oscillator()` method is incompatible with the type that `RtAudio.openStream()` accepts.

It works fine if `oscillator()` is `static`, presumably because the implicit `this` pointer passed into the method changes its type.  However, I can't have it be `static` because I need `oscillator()` to have access to `Instrument` fields (for stuff like amplitude and frequency).

Is there any sort of quick solution that requires a minimal amount of wrappers and such?

Comment: What is the signature of `startStream`?

Comment: non-`static` members have that hidden `this` parameter to watch out for. Easiest thing to do is add a `static` member function that casts the user argument to an `Instrument` instance, and then invokes the non-`static` method on the instance.

Comment: As a tangent, do you normally indent three spaces? What things have you seen...

Comment: I used to indent three until life beat me into using four.

Comment: Remove the `&`. Just use the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RtAudio::openStream()` takes a user-defined parameter as input to the callback, per the documentation:

https://rtaudio.docsforge.com/master/api/RtAudio/openStream/

> ```
> void openStream(..., RtAudioCallback callback, void *userData=NULL, ...)
> ```
>
> public function for opening a stream with the specified parameters.
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ...
>
> `callback` - A client-defined function that will be invoked when input data is available and/or output data is needed.
>
> `userData` - An optional pointer to data that can be accessed from within the callback function.
>
> ...

https://rtaudio.docsforge.com/master/api/#RtAudioCallback

> ```
> typedef int(* RtAudioCallback)(..., void *userData)
> ```
>
> RtAudio callback function prototype.
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `userData` - A pointer to optional data provided by the client when opening the stream (default = NULL).
>
> ...

That `userData` parameter will allow you to pass your `Instrument*` object pointer to a `static` callback, eg:

```cpp
class Instrument {
private:
    int static_oscillator(void *outputBuffer, void *inputBuffer, unsigned int nFrames, double streamTime, RtAudioStreamStatus status, void *userData) {
        return static_cast<Instrument*>(userData)->oscillator(outputBuffer, inputBuffer, nFrames, streamTime, status);
    }

    int oscillator(void *outputBuffer, void *inputBuffer, unsigned int nFrames, double streamTime, RtAudioStreamStatus status) {
        // Writes a sine wave to outputBuffer
        return ...;
    }  

    RtAudio output;  // Object for outputting audio

public:
    void start() {
        output.openStream(..., &static_oscillator, this, ...);
        ...
    }
};
```